# Proving that Every Full Prefix-Free Language is Maximal

Tags: proof-techniques, sets

I'm practicing a problem where I need to prove that every full prefix-free language is maximal.

I know a prefix-free language A is maximal if it is not a proper subset of any prefix-free language, where a prefix-free language is full if,

$$\sum_{x\in A} 2^{-|x|} = 1$$

Furthermore, I know that a language A ⊆ {0, 1}* is prefix-free if no element of A is a prefix of any other element of A and that the Kraft inequality says that for every prefix-free language A,

$$\sum_{x\in A} 2^{-|x|} \leqslant 1$$

I'm pretty sure that a full prefix free language is maximal, since it belongs to the maximal prefix-free set. I don't know, however, how to formally prove this. Should I be doing induction with Kraft's Inequality and with what I know about the relationship between maximal and prefix-free sets?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ is a full prefix-free language, that is,
$$
\sum_{x \in A} 2^{-|x|} = 1.
$$
Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $A$ is not maximal. Then there is a word $y$ such that $A \cup \{y\}$ is also prefix-free. According to Kraft's inequality,
$$
\sum_{x \in A \cup \{y\}} 2^{-|x|} \leq 1.
$$
However, this implies that
$$
1 \geq \sum_{x \in A} 2^{-|x|} + 2^{-|y|} = 1 + 2^{-|y|} > 1,
$$
and so we reach a contradiction. This shows that $A$ is maximal.

---

The more interesting direction is the converse: if $A$ is maximal then $A$ is full. Let me give two proofs of this fact.

The first proof is by induction on the length of the maximal word in $A$ (note that if $A$ is maximal then it cannot be empty). If $A = \{\epsilon\}$ then $A$ is indeed full. Now suppose that $A$ contains some word of positive length. Since $A$ is prefix-free, $\epsilon \notin A$. Hence we can write
$$
A = \{ 0x : x \in A_0 \} \cup \{ 1x : x \in A_1 \},
$$
where $A_0,A_1$ are prefix-free, and have shorter maximal words. It is easy to check that $A_0,A_1$ are maximal: for example, if $A_0 \cup \{y\}$ were prefix-free, then $A \cup \{0y\}$ would be prefix-free. Applying the induction hypothesis, we see that
$$
\sum_{x \in A} 2^{-|x|} = \sum_{x \in A_0} 2^{-|0x|} + \sum_{x \in A_1} 2^{-|1x|} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x \in A_0} 2^{-|x|} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x \in A_1} 2^{-|x|} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1.
$$

The second proof uses a probabilistic argument, though for the sake of presentation I will present it as a counting argument. Let $A$ be a prefix-free code which is not maximal, and let $n$ be the length of the maximal word in $A$. For a word $x$ of length at most $n$, let $B_n(x)$ denote all words of length $n$ of which $x$ is a prefix, and note that $|B_n(x)| = 2^{n-|x|}$. Since $A$ is prefix-free, the sets $B_n(x)$ for $x \in A$ are all disjoint. Therefore
$$
\left| \bigcup_{x \in A} B_n(x) \right| = \sum_{x \in A} |B_n(x)| = \sum_{x \in A} 2^{n-|x|} = 2^n \sum_{x \in A} 2^{-|x|} < 2^n.
$$
Therefore there is some word $w$ of length $n$ which has no word in $A$ as a prefix. So $A \cup \{w\}$ is also prefix-free, and we conclude that $A$ is not maximal.

---

Both proofs we presented above actually show the following stronger fact: every prefix-free code is a subset of a maximal prefix-free code. Let me quickly outline how to obtain this result using both proofs.

In the first proof, we prove the claim by induction. If $A = \emptyset$ then we can extend it to $A = \{\epsilon\}$, and if $A = \{\epsilon\}$ then $A$ is already maximal. So suppose that $A = 0A_0 \cup 1A_1$. The induction hypothesis shows how to extend $A_0,A_1$ to maximal prefix-free codes $B_0,B_1$ (respectively), and then $B = 0B_0 \cup 1B_1$ is maximal.

In the second proof, we obtain a maximal prefix-free code by adding to $A$ all words in
$$
\overline{\bigcup_{x \in A} B_n(x)}.
$$

In both proofs, one way to check that the extended code is maximal is by verifying that it is full.

---

For extra credit, the reader can try extending the ideas above to infinite prefix-free codes, that is, prefix-free codes containing countably many words.

Comment: Nice exposition.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, I am afraid, you have done little useful thinking after a lot of typing. Well, that does happen a lot to me as well when it is about a new field.

---

Let $A$ be a full prefix-free language over alphabet $\{0,1\}$, i.e., 
$$\sum_{x\in A} 2^{-|x|} = 1\,.$$

For the sake of contradiction, assume $A$ is not maximal. That is, there exists a word $y\not\in A$ such that $B=A\cup\{y\}$ is a prefix-free language. Then

$$\sum_{x\in B} 2^{-|x|} =  2^{-|y|} + \sum_{x\in A} 2^{-|x|} = 2^{-|y|} + 1 >1\,,$$ 
which contradicts the Kraft inequality.

Done.

---

Here are several related exercises. Note the alphabet is assumed to be finite.

**Exercise 1**. Show that a full prefix-free language over any alphabet must be maximal.

**Exercise 2**. Show that a maximal prefix-free finite language over any alphabet must be full.

**Exercise 3**. Show that a maximal prefix-free infinite language over any alphabet must be full.